# java mysql disk full

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, crash

I have a java/mysql application. I am writing huge data to mysql using my java application. But in some cases due to Disk full condition, mysql is crashing. Is it possible to handle mysql diskfull scenario from java/jdbc?

regards

Comment: Please post a) The error you get from JDBC b) What you were trying to do when the disc became full c) All errors in the mysql server error log. What engine you're using may be helpful too. MySQL should not crash when the disc becomes full (but its behaviour, in my experience, is not always helpful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to handle mysql diskfull scenario from java/jdbc?

Well yes.  This will manifest itself as a failure in a JDBC update statement, which you can presumably detect based on the exception's (MySQL specific) code.

However, once you've caught the exception, I doubt that there is much that you can do to recover.  If the disc is full you need human intervention to resolve the problem; e.g. to look for files that can be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

It checks once every minute to see whether there is enough space to write the current row. If there is enough space, it continues as if nothing had happened.

Every 10 minutes it writes an entry to the log file, warning about the disk-full condition.

Refer below link :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/full-disk.html

Try to handle mysql error code : 28 (for disk full) through your java code.

Answer (score 0):

The disk full condition is detected and handled by MySQL, the result is that your INSERT query fails. If you want to handle it in Java, handle the failed INSERT.

Comment: I imagine that other SQL statements could fail too.